# .append() me crea dos elementos Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Hago click en un span y me crea dos input Nombre en vez de uno

```js
$(document).ready(inicio);

function inicio(){
    $("#agregar").click(agregarBicicleta);
}
function agregarBicicleta(){
    $("#formBici").append("<div class='nuevaBici'><input type='text' placeholder='Nombre'></div>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formBici" style="position: relative; top: 30vh;">
  <div class="nuevaBici">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
  </div>
</form>
<span id="agregar" style="position: relative; top: 30vh; cursor: pointer;">Agregar bicicleta</span>
```

Comment: lo que deberia hacer es cambiar esto: function inicio(){
    $("#agregar").click(agregarBicicleta);
}......por esto ... $("#agregar").click(agregarBicicleta);...es decir fuera de function inicio

Comment: Yo lo veo trabajando bien, revisaste la consola en tu navegador a ver si tienes alguna incompatibilidad?

Comment: Yo también lo veo bien.

Comment: no tengo ningun error en la consola, y tambien probe lo que me dijo Diego Avila.
Ustedes lo probaron?

Comment: si en efecto funciona bien

Comment: puedes revisarlo aca: https://jsfiddle.net/tw8ysqh9/

Comment: Si ya vi que funciona ahí, creo que el problema es un conflico con Angular Cli, pero no se cual seria el problema